# User defined function in MySQL (C/C++ extension Plugin). Can't execute system command

Tags: c++, mysql, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create User defined function for MySQL(accordind this documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/extending-mysql/8.0/en/adding-loadable-function.html) and create new command my_udf which will run Python script via system call, but it doesn't work.

```
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

extern "C" bool my_udf_init(UDF_INIT* initid, UDF_ARGS* args, char* message)
{
    if (args->arg_count != 1 || args->arg_type[0] != STRING_RESULT) {
        strcpy(message, "Expected a single string argument");
        return 1;
    }

    initid->const_item = 1;     // This UDF is deterministic
    initid->maybe_null = 1;     // This UDF can return NULL
    initid->max_length = 0;     // The result can be of any length

    return 0;
}

extern "C" char* my_udf(UDF_INIT* initid, UDF_ARGS* args, char* result,
                        unsigned long* length, char* is_null, char* error)
{
    // Print the input string
    

    // Run the Python script and pass the input string as a command-line parameter
    char param[] = "params to script";
    char cmd[100];
    sprintf(cmd, "python3 checker.py %s", param);
    system(cmd);

    return 0;
}
```

With my Python script all ok, I checked twice.

Problem with call system(cmd), I think.

Comment: Your code is C++, not C.  And your C++ compiler should be complaining about it, because you cannot overload functions that have C linkage.

Comment: i'm trying to do according to this documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/extending-mysql/8.0/en/adding-loadable-function.html#loadable-function-calling . You are right it is c++, it is compiled, mysql understand this function but my script not running

Comment: How do you determine that the script does not run?

Comment: from python script i send INSERT to mysql. Also i checked by running python script from console, and running python code from dummy c code without wrapping into mysql plugin

Comment: So you *don't* know that the script does not run.  You know only that you do not observe the expected inserts.  It is conceivable that something about the execution environment when the script is launched from mysql via your function prevents the inserts from succeeding.  Or similar. I would suggest figuring out a way to check the return value of the `system()` call.  That will tell you about whether the script was actually run, and if so, what its exit status was.

Comment: my script working properly, I checked the environment before

Comment: You cannot have "checked the environment before" and found the script to be working, because the environment that matters is the one where you claim the script is not running at all.  And perhaps it indeed is not running, but again, the evidence you have described for that is not sufficient to support the conclusion.  Check the return value of `system()`.  That will tell you something that you do not already know.  What that will be, I cannot predict.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253548/discussion-between-alexander-vedmed-and-john-bollinger).